# How to make CloudFlare cache everything?

Tags: cache, cdn, optimization, static-content, cloudflare

I want CloudFlare to cache everything, PHP files too, every request from the domain,
I want it to cache it.

Is this possible?

(There are PHP scripts on the domain that print out images, JS and CSS, they return the appropriate mime type, but I read that CloudFlare caches according to file extenstion, if printing out the mime type helps, it's good too.)

Comment: PHP files could return different things at different times so I doubt that CloudFare would cache them. If they really do return the same thing every time then why not make them images/js/CSS files so they get cached?

Comment: They change but rarely, the cache for CloudFlare is for 24 hours which is fine with me. CloudFlare also has an option to flush the cache in case I change them manually.

Answer (score 7):

This wasn't possible when you asked the question. This is now possible with [PageRules](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-advanced-caching).

Note: You want to exclude the admin section of your site with a PageRule as well. If you do cache everything and the admin section is included, you will likely see some sort of looping error.

Comment: if I uploaded files to my WordPress upload folder .. small files not more than 30 MB and offered links for users to download if I used page rule like this
*site.com/wp-content/uploads*
can I make Cloudflare cache those files to my visitors when they try to download it, those files, not images most likely website app APK and some zip files but with a huge bandwidth consumption